# django jquery post then load

Tags: django, jquery, jquery-load, jquery-post

Trying to get a section on my site working when it basically acts in the same way as `facebooks wall post`

user sees a box where they input some information about how they feel, then I use a `jQuery $.post` method to submit the data, and then I would like to retrive the new data.

Currently this is what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#testform").submit(function(){
        $.post("/wall/new/", $("#testform").serialize());
        $('#id_text').val('');
        $(this).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('#news').load('/wall/');
        });
        return false;

    });
</script>
```

And then the HTML looks like this

```
<div id="news">
    <h4>{% trans "News feed" %}</h4>

    <form method="post" action="/wall/new/" id="testform">
        <textarea id="id_text" class="wall-input" style="max-height: 100px;" rows="1" name="text"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'share' %}" class="blue" id="submit-wall"/>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what exact problem you are facing. The code you have given looks OK; id it not working?

Comment: You may have a reason why you should first POST then GET the data back, but I would avoid it. Why not make a POST, see if it returns OK, and if it does just append the data the user provided directly in HTML with jQuery. You would save a request per post, but this method is not always convenient (if you need to process the data server side for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.get seemed to solve the issue instead

```
$(this).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.get('/wall/', { user:'myuser'}, function(data){
        $('#news').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are wedded to handling all of the AJAX detail yourself, take a look at the [jQuery taconite plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/taconite/). It makes [fire-and-forget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire-and-forget) AJAX functionality trivial to implement.